# See detail log in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http

I write following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.print(conn.getResponseMessage());
}
```

1. I want show all debug information in console when i run this method.
2. I want see what kind of http request have been sent from log.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Java uses by default [*Java Logging*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html#package_description), add the following code:

```
static {
    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
    log.addHandler(handler);
    log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. The output appears in the most detailed level, `FINEST`, but that depends on the vendor (IBM, Oracle, OpenJDK) of the virtual machine.

Comment: Almost complete answer except it won't show POST body. you need to also do this: System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");

Answer (score 3):

//2. simple header informations:

```
conn.getHeaderFields().toString(); //response headers
conn.getResponseCode();//response http code
conn.getRequestProperties().toString();//request headers
```